# Working with Radio button list in Sitecore XSLT

Tags: list, xslt, radio-button, sitecore

I am working on Radio Button list, where on selecting a radio button in the page (representing cities),I need to show list of Institutions in the city in XSLT Sitecore .Here I get the list of institutions from an external webservice, so I need to pass as unique ID of the city(which is stored as value of a radio button) to the webservice. Below is the code that I am using to do the same.

```
  <xsl:variable  name="city" select="sc:GetCityUniqueID()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ID" select="sc:item($city,.)" />
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>

      <td valign="top">
      <!--In the SiteCore Content Tree we are maintaining Institutions as Child Nodes to Cities.So using for each I am populating radio buttons with those many institutions under a city.Here Please note that I am setting Value to the ID which I need to pass to the Helpwr Function sc:GetInstitutions below-->
       <xsl:variable name="cities" select="$content/child::item[@template='city institution details']"/>
       <xsl:if test="$cities " >

        <xsl:for-each select="$icities"  >
         <xsl:variable name="current" select="."></xsl:variable>
         <input type="radio" Groupname="citylist">
          <xsl:attribute name="id" >
           city<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="name" >city</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="value" >
           <sc:text field="Institute ID" select="$current" />
          </xsl:attribute>
         </input>
         <span class="chooseCity">
          <sc:text field="Name" select="$current" />

         </span>
         <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:if>
      </td>


     </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="institution_results">    
       Institutions are:
    </div>




<div class="paddAll">
<!--Here 123456 should be the selected radio buttons value above,which I am passing to external webservice call done in the helper to populate Institutions-->
    <xsl:value-of select="sc:GetInstitutions('123456’)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

    </div>
```

The problem I am facing here is how can I pass the selected radio button value to the XSL Helper function to get the list of Institutions and display the results in the same page below.

Any Suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to do something that is hard to accomplish in XSLT and could be easily done by using a SubLayout (ASCX) with a postback event on the dropdownlist-change-event instead of using a rendering (XSLT) in which you don't have something like a postback.
Renderings are primarily used for displaying simple texts and list, no fancy stuff.
If you want to persist on doing this in xslt, you might accomplish this with the use of jQuery AJAX but I recommend to change this rendering for a SubLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SiteCore, but [this blog](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/Accessing%20Field%20Values.aspx) suggests accessing field values via the `sc:fld()` function, and [this blog](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/04/sitecore-rendering-parameters-friday.html) seems to have instructions on accessing SiteCore fields by way of parameters.  Have you tried either of those approaches?

Once you successfully get the value into your XSLT (assuming the parameter or variable name "city" here), I presume you should be able to use it like this, assuming the `sc:GetInstitutions()` function actually exists:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sc:GetInstitutions($city)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```